# Internet connection control in a network

Tags: networking, router, internet

I would like to know if there is some software (preferentially free) to accomplish that kind of features:

- Restrict access to some websites
- Reduce bandwidth for some websites (like youtube, etc) or services (like P2P)
- Manage bandwidth between users (like user1:60% - user2:20% - user3:10%)

There is that kind of software?

Answer (score 2):

pfsense ([http://www.pfsense.com/](http://www.squidguard.org)) and [squidguard](http://www.squidguard.org) would do what you are looking for.

It's not just software though - it would require setting up a gateway box for the group of users you are trying to control. Setting it up with pfsense is fairly simple though, and IIRC it does have a squidguard package that is installable through the front end.

Not quite windows-network, however... :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [ebox-platform](http://ebox-platform.com/), it has some nice features to control bandwidth and quality of service.